# SPARQL select instance of equivalent class

Tags: sparql, protege

I'm trying to create SPARQL query that returns individuals which are an instance of an equivalent class expression (thus imitating some of the reasoning skills of protégé on Semantic Web). Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? I have a class named 'violation' which contains an equivalent class restriction. Now I want to find the individuals that meet the conditions of this restriction.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT distinct ?Carmovement ?person ?restriction ?message
WHERE {?Carmovement carmovement:has_driver ?person .
       ?Carmovement rdf:type ?restriction . #rdf:type is no succes for getting instances
?object owl:equivalentClass ?restriction .
?object violin:message ?message}`
```

The query does not give any results because I have used "rdf:type", I wonder in which way I can evaluate whether an instance meets the condition of a class restriction.

Sample class restriction:

```
owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
owl:intersectionOf ( 
<http://desibo.frsf.utn.edu.ar/ontologies/2012/9/CarMovement.owl#Car_Movement>
                   [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                     owl:onProperty <http://desibo.frsf.utn.edu.ar/ontologies/2012/9/CarMovement.owl#has_driver> ;
                     owl:allValuesFrom <http://desibo.frsf.utn.edu.ar/ontologies/2012/9/CarMovement.owl#BarredPerson>
                   ]
                 )
                ] ;
```

I expect to get individuals who have a property "has_driver" of type "BarredPerson".

Comment: Your query would only work for subclasses of the class expression. In order to individuals, clearly you have to check for instances that have the property (`owl:someValuesFrom`) or as in your example if the individuals have the property, then only those with an object of the given type. Double negation is the way to go: `?s ?p ?o. FILTER NOT EXISTS {?s :has_driver ?o1. FILTER NOT EXISTS {?o1 rdf:type :BarredPerson}}` - (this will be logically incomplete without reasoning and/or property path)

Comment: I can get the individuals I need for this specific purpose: 
`SELECT distinct ?Carmovement ?person
WHERE {?Carmovement carmovement:has_driver ?person .
 ?person rdf:type carmovement:BarredPerson}` (your query would also work), but I am looking for a way to make this query generic, so I can get indiduals that have matching properties for ANY equivalent class